# Populate data in EF Core Migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a data class which has a Guid as the Id and it also contains nested objects. Now I have the requirement to populate this Guid in all nested objects as an additional property. If I just add the property and run the usual `dotnet ef migrations add xyz` command the Guids will have the default value instead of the Guids from the parent objects.

Is there a way to populate the parent Guid automatically in a migration?

Comment: Have you looked into data seeding? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. add new property as optional
2. add new migration
3. programmatically set Guid value in all nested objects
4. set your new property as non optional
5. add new migration